# A square appears randomly within a square of ten time its area. What is probability that the smaller square contains the larger square's center?

Tags: probability, geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, problem-solving

The alignment relative to the larger square can be anywhere between 0° to 90° (0° or 90° being identical orientation to the larger square, 45° being all the way skewed), and the probability distribution of the alignment is based on percentage of total possibility given the constraint guaranteeing that it will fit within the larger square.

<s>The largest discrete probability, for an alignment of 0°=90°, should be simple enough to figure-out‡. The smallest discrete probability, for alignment of 45°, is a bit trickier but straightforward enough.</s>**Edit**:The off-kilter version would be more likely to contain the center, since it has less possible places to exist and a larger proportion of them are the center. Intuitively this should correspond directly (though not necessarily uniformly) to what I am totally clueless about, which is:

1. how to determine the probability  distribution for between 0° to 45°,

‡ 2. how this continuum corresponds to the probability of the original problem (e.g. {1/17?} for 0° up to {2/9?} for 45° back down to {1/17?} for 90°, along finite part of some sort of curve function presumably),

and 3. how then to apply these equations formulated into the original problem to find the final probability that a square true-randomly generated wholly within a larger square with sides √(10)-times longer would surround (or contain exactly on an edge or corner) the center of the larger square.

‡ I haven't calculated the maximum or minimum ‘discrete’ probabilities (let alone any inbetween) yet. Those guesstimate values are placeholders. I am especially interested in the processes required to solve this, and appreciate any insight or clues.

Comment: What does it mean that the small square "appears randomly"? The angle of rotation is chosen uniformly at random (and then the translation is chosen also uniformly at random, subject to the containment constraint)? Or...?

Comment: I just realized that the ratio I chose would make the probability 100%, since side length of larger square is less than four times that of the smaller one.  A more suitable ratio of area would be maybe 50 or 100, or 7 or 10 of length

Comment: @user7530  Think of it this way: you are given that that the smaller square will appear in the larger one. Any placement and rotation that allows for this is possible; some may be more likely than others, however. There is no ‘rotation’ strictly speaking, since you aren't given an 'initial’ alignment; all you are given is that the smaller square is guaranteed to be inside the larger, and that the smaller one doesn’t ‘prefer’ any particular relative alignment. Some alignments offer more ‘possibilities’, however, for the smaller square to fit inside the larger one.

Comment: The two relationships are (I suspect) inversely proportional but not at equal rates.

Comment: @math: To be clear ... Is this a problem of your own devising (as opposed to a textbook exercise or contest question where a "nice" and/or straightforward solution might be expected)?

Comment: Correct, my own devising; no "nice" or surprisingly compact answer to be expected. (I would gladly use values that are nicer, if those exist and I know what they are, but this problem is more for learning how even to do this type of problem than specific values, much of which is over my current understanding).

Comment: @math: Regarding "all you are given is that the smaller square is guaranteed to be inside the larger, and that the smaller one doesn't 'prefer' any particular relative alignment": That isn't enough to determine a probability, however. In order to answer the question unambiguously, one needs to know the random process that produces the smaller square. Suppose the larger square is the unit square with lower-left corner at the origin. Two reasonably natural options are: (a) Select a point $P$ uniformly from the unit square, and an angle $\theta$ uniformly from the interval $[0, \pi/2]$. (cont'd)

Comment: Now, produce a square centered at point $P$ and rotated by angle $\theta$.  If the small square falls entirely within the larger unit square, then accept it; otherwise, reject it and choose a new $P'$ and $\theta'$.  Repeat until you succeed. Or (b) Select an angle $\theta$ uniformly from the interval $[0, \pi/2]$.  *Then* select a point $P$ from the unit square.  If the small square fits entirely within the unit square, then accept it.  Otherwise, *keep* $\theta$ but pick a new point $P'$ and try again.  Keep selecting new center points with the same angle $\theta$ until you succeed. (cont'd)

Comment: These two are different processes; in particular, (b) gives a uniform angle of rotation, and (a) doesn't.  Accordingly, I would expect them to yield two different (though probably very nearly the same) answers.  It's conceivable that they yield the same answer (I'd be pretty surprised), but if so, that has to be shown.

Comment: @Brian Tung  Is there not one that blends these two?  Any comment regarding Mushu Nrek's answer procedure? Given the parameters stated in the problem statement, one is not to "perform one operation before the other", but to weigh it based on total probability space of the solution. Whether the outside or inside square gets 'created' first shouldn't make a difference provided the constraint is satisfied, though I find more natural thinking of the smaller inside one as poofing into existence second, although the relationship is co-dependent.

Comment: @math: I don't think so.  They are two different probability distributions.  You can pick one, or you can pick the other, but you can't pick both.

Comment: @BrianTung Can you explain, why some process should be more intuitive than taking the centre and the angle uniformly from all possibilities? It is surely a bit more abstract, but in my belief the most intuitive answer when asking for a "truly random" choice of the smaller square. If I understand it well, this would be your option a). Indeed, the text wasn't specifying anything rigourously, but anyway it is just a fun problem to play around with!

Comment: @MushuNrek: It's not that it should be more intuitive.  It's that there are multiple reasonable (to my mind) interpretations that yield different answers.  OP has created their own problem.  They can choose any interpretation, and I'm not expecting them to justify the interpretation—it's their problem.  But to answer the question precisely, it should be made clear which interpretation that is. :-)

Comment: math, @BrianTung is absolutely right $-$ the answer depends on exactly how you select your "random" square. You are not taking this issue seriously, but it is important! You must be must be specific about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Without Rotation

Suppose a square of side $s\le\frac12$ is placed randomly inside a unit square, without rotation. The probability that the $x$-coordinate of the center of the unit square is within the $x$-span of the smaller square is $\frac{s}{1-s}$. That is, when covering the center of the unit square, the left side of the smaller square can be $s$ to $0$ units to the left of the center of the unit square, while, without restriction, the left side of  the smaller square can go from $1$ to $s$ units to the left of the right side of the unit square. The same is true for the $y$-coordinate. So the probability that the center of the larger square is within the smaller square is
$$
\left(\frac{s}{1-s}\right)^2\tag1
$$
In your question, $s=\frac1{\sqrt{10}}$, which gives a probability of
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac1{11-2\sqrt{10}}\approx0.213883399}\tag2
$$

---

#### With Rotation

**Geometry and Probability**

The smaller square rotated by $0\le\theta\le\frac\pi4$ will span a width and height of
$$
d=s(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))\tag3
$$
Note that $(3)$ says that $d:\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]\mapsto\left[s,s\sqrt2\right]$ monotonically.

If the smaller square is to stay inside the unit square, its center is constrained to a non-rotated square of side $1-d$ concentric with the unit square (shown below as a red square).  If the center of the unit square is to be inside the smaller square, the center of the smaller square needs to be inside a square with the same size and rotation, but concentric with the unit square (shown below as a green square).

Thus, the locus of the center of the smaller square so that the smaller square is contained in the unit square, and so that the smaller square contains the center of the unit square is the intersection of the red and green squares (shown below in purple).

[image]

For a given size and rotation of the smaller square, given that the smaller square is contained in the unit square, the probability that the center of the unit square is inside the smaller square is the ratio of the area of the purple region divided by the area of the red square.

However, to get the proper weighting of the probabilities for the different angles, we need to weight the probabilities by the area of the red square since that is the probability that the rotated square is contained in the unit square. This means we compute the integral of the area of the purple region and divide that by the integral of the area of the red region.

**Computation of the Areas**

The area of the red square is
$$
\begin{align}
\text{area}_\text{red}
&=(1-d)^2\tag{4a}\\[6pt]
&=(1-s(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)))^2\tag{4b}\\[6pt]
&=1-2s(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))+s^2(1+2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta))\tag{4c}\\
\int_0^{\pi/4}\text{area}_\text{red}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\frac\pi4-2s+\left(\frac\pi4+\frac12\right)s^2\tag{4d}
\end{align}
$$
If $d\le\frac12$, then, because $d\lt1-d$, the green square is completely contained within the red square and so the area of the purple region is
$$
\begin{align}
\text{area}_\text{purple}
&=s^2\tag{5a}\\
\int\text{area}_\text{purple}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\theta s^2\tag{5b}\\
&=a_1(s,\theta)\tag{5c}
\end{align}
$$
We leave $\text{(5b)}$ indefinite since we may need to restrict $\theta$ due to the condition $d\le\frac12$.

For $d\gt\frac12$, we will refer to the following diagram:

[image]

Since the side length of the red square $1-d$ and the height of the rotated green square is $d$, the four corners of the green square that extend beyond the red square have altitude $\frac{d-(1-d)}2=d-\frac12$ and base $\frac{d-1/2}{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}$. If the bases of these triangles are smaller than the sides of the red square, then $\frac{d-1/2}{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}\lt1-d$, which is equivalent to $d\lt\frac{1+\sin(2\theta)}{2+\sin(2\theta)}$.

Thus, if $\frac12\lt d\lt\frac{1+\sin(2\theta)}{2+\sin(2\theta)}$, the area of the purple region is
$$
\begin{align}
\text{area}_\text{purple}
&=s^2-\frac{2(d-1/2)^2}{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}\tag{6a}\\
&=s^2-\frac{2\left(s(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))-\frac12\right)^2}{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}\tag{6b}\\[3pt]
&=\scriptsize-\frac12\csc(\theta)\sec(\theta)+2(\csc(\theta)+\sec(\theta))s-(3+2\csc(\theta)\sec(\theta))s^2\tag{6c}\\[6pt]
\int\text{area}_\text{purple}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\scriptsize-\frac12\log(\tan(\theta))+2\log\left(\tan\left(\tfrac\theta2\right)\tan\left(\tfrac\pi4{+}\tfrac\theta2\right)\right)s-\left(3\theta+2\log(\tan(\theta))\right)s^2\tag{6d}\\[9pt]
&=a_2(s,\theta)\tag{6e}
\end{align}
$$
If $d\ge\frac{1+\sin(2\theta)}{2+\sin(2\theta)}$, the red square is completely contained within the green square and so the area of the purple region is the same as the area of the red square:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{area}_\text{purple}
&=(1-d)^2\tag{7a}\\[3pt]
&=(1-s(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)))^2\tag{7b}\\[3pt]
&=1-2(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))s+(1+2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta))s^2\tag{7c}\\
\int\text{area}_\text{purple}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\theta-2(\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta))s+\left(\theta+\sin^2(\theta)\right)s^2\tag{7d}\\
&=a_3(s,\theta)\tag{7e}
\end{align}
$$
**Conditional Ranges**

We need to apply each of $a_1$, $a_2$, or $a_3$ over particular parts of $\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]$. That is, we use $a_1$ over the green region of the chart below, $a_2$ over the yellow region, and $a_3$ over the red region.

[image]

To simplify the usage of the information in the chart above, define
$$
\theta_1(s)=\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1-4s^2}{4s^2}\right)\tag8
$$
and
$$
\theta_2(s)=\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1-4s^2+\sqrt{1-4s^2}}{2s^2}\right)\tag9
$$

If $s\le\frac1{2\sqrt2}$, we use $a_1$ for all $\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]$. That is, the probability of the randomly rotated and positioned smaller square containing the center of the unit square is
$$
\frac{a_1\!\left(s,\frac\pi4\right)-a_1\!\left(s,0\right)}{a_3\!\left(s,\frac\pi4\right)-a_3\!\left(s,0\right)}=\frac{\frac\pi4s^2}{\frac\pi4-2s+\left(\frac\pi4+\frac12\right)s^2}\tag{10}
$$
If $\frac1{2\sqrt2}\lt s\le\frac{\sqrt2}3$, we use $a_1$ over $\theta\in[0,\theta_1(s)]$ and $a_2$ over $\theta\in\left[\theta_1(s),\frac\pi4\right]$. That is, the probability of the randomly rotated and positioned smaller square containing the center of the unit square is
$$
\frac{a_2\!\left(s,\frac\pi4\right)-a_2(s,\theta_1(s))+a_1(s,\theta_1(s))-a_1(s,0)}
{a_3\!\left(s,\frac\pi4\right)-a_3\!\left(s,0\right)}\tag{11}
$$
If $\frac{\sqrt2}3\lt s\le\frac12$, we use $a_1$ over $\theta\in[0,\theta_1(s)]$, $a_2$ over $\theta\in[\theta_1(s),\theta_2(s)]$, and $a_3$ over $\theta\in\left[\theta_2(s),\frac\pi4\right]$. That is, the probability of the randomly rotated and positioned smaller square containing the center of the unit square is
$$
\frac{a_3\!\left(s,\frac\pi4\right)-a_3(s,\theta_2(s))+a_2(s,\theta_2(s))-a_2(s,\theta_1(s))+a_1(s,\theta_1(s))-a_1(s,0)}
{a_3\!\left(s,\frac\pi4\right)-a_3\!\left(s,0\right)}\tag{12}
$$
In the question, $s=\frac1{\sqrt{10}}$, so we apply $(10)$ and get a probability of
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac\pi{11\pi+2-8\sqrt{10}}\approx0.279022074}\tag{13}
$$
Here is a plot of the probability that a randomly rotated and positioned square of side $s$ inside the unit square contains the origin of the unit square:

[image]

---

**Simulation**

I ran a simulation placing the center of the smaller square, with side $s$, uniformly in a square, concentric with the unit square, and with side $1-s$, and rotating uniformly with $\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]$.

All trials where the translated and rotated square did not fit completely in the unit square were rejected. The remaining trials were tallied counting those where the center of the unit square fell within the smaller square.

The results of $10,\!000,\!000$ trials with $s=\frac1{\sqrt{10}}$ were

non-rejected trials: $7,\!664,\!102$
successful trials: $2,\!136,\!729$
ratio: $0.278797046$

This is close to $0.279022074$.

Here is the Mathematica code for the simulation:

```
test[s_, x_, y_, \[Theta]_] := 
 Module[{c = {x - 1/2, y - 1/2} (1 - s), 
   m = s {{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {-Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}},
   u = 1/2 {{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
   cross = (#1.{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}.#2) &, ul, ur, lr, ll},
   {ul, ur, lr, ll} = u.m + {c, c, c, c}; 
  If[Max[Abs[ul], Abs[ur], Abs[lr], Abs[ll]] > 1/2, {0, 0}, 
   If[Min[cross[ur, ul], cross[ul, ll], cross[ll, lr], cross[lr, ur]] < 0,
    {0, 1}, {1, 1}]]]
```

```
Module[{s = 1/Sqrt[10], n = 10000000, data = {0, 0}}, 
 Do[data += test[s, RandomReal[1], RandomReal[1], RandomReal[Pi/4]], n];
 data]
```

Comment: Thank you for the robust explanation with visuals!  If you feel so-inclined, here are two semi-related questions I asked:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3966498/867884 (triangle within circle vs. circle within triangle), https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3967544/867884 (general geometric probability).

Comment: How did you run the simulation? What program?

Comment: The code is Mathematica code. I used Mathematica for all the illustrations and for the simulation.  The simulation took about 10 minutes to run on my 5 year old Mac laptop,

Comment: Is that a premium feature of Wolfram Alpha? What is meant by its 'RandomReal' function as you used it?   Also I have ane related tough extraneous question on the whole problem I'm pondering, that might interest you: How would you determine the 5° {= π/36 rad} range of angles theta (correctly weighted) that represent tilt between 0 to π/4 rad inclusive (of the small square wrt the larger one containing it) that have the highest probability of yielding a successful inclusion of the larger square's center? Would this maximum correspond to the peak derivative positive slope of the (cont'd..)

Comment: (..cont'd) yellow 'conditional' probability area inverted? Inflection point? And the least probable theta values[s]s would be where the slope is closest to 0, namely at π/4 rad? How would you find the exact values within the specified range? If this intuition is correct, then they should be close to [{22.5,45}±2.5]°, but not exactly since the curve is not formed by a uniform rectangle or straight lines.

Comment: [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) is the program that inspired Wolfram Alpha. [RandomReal](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html)[x] gives a random real number in $[0,x]$.

Comment: For a given $s\le\frac{\sqrt2}3$, the highest probability of containing the center occurs at $\theta=\frac\pi4$. For $\frac{\sqrt2}3\le s\le\frac12$ and angles greater than $\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1-4s^2+\sqrt{1-4s^2}}{2s^2}\right)$, the center of the bigger square will always be inside the smaller square. For $s\ge\frac12$, the center of the bigger square will always be inside the smaller square.

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I understand you problem.

You are looking at a square $S = [-R/2, R/2]^2$ of side length $R$ (for simplicity centred at the origin. I will write $C(x;\theta)$ for the smaller square of side length $r$ centred in $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ at rotation $\theta$. You want to know what the probability is of the event that $0\in C(x;\theta)$ under the constraint $C(x;\theta)\subseteq S$.

For simplicity, we take $r \ll R$ in a suitable sense ($=$ so that everything works just fine). The first thing I would like to do is to wrap it up mathematically. For this, we define our probability space to be
$$
\Omega := \{(x,\theta)\in \mathbb{R}^2\times [0,\pi/4]\;\vert\; C(x;\theta)\subseteq S\}.
$$
Note that I only consider angles up to 45 degrees, because the situation is symmetric for angles between 45 and 90 degrees. To model "random appearance", we take the uniform distribution on $\Omega$.

First things first: Can we describe $\Omega$? For this, fix the angle $\theta$. Write $h(\theta)$ for the height ($=$ the width) of the skewed square $C(x;\theta)$. Then
$$
h(\theta) = \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4} - \theta\right)\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot r.
$$
We conclude that
$$
\Omega = \{(x,\theta)\in \mathbb{R}^2\times [0,\pi/4]\;\vert\; \Vert x\Vert_\infty \leq (R - h(\theta))/2\}.
$$
In particular,
$$
m(\Omega) = \int_0^{\pi/4} \big{(} R - r\cos(\theta)\sqrt{2}\big{)}^2\mathrm{d}{\theta} = \dfrac{\pi}{4}R^2 - 2Rr + \dfrac{2+\pi}{4}r^2,
$$
where I wrote $m$ for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now to the event we are interested in:
$$
A = \{(x,\theta)\in \Omega\;\vert\; 0\in C(x;\theta)\}.
$$
Since we took $r\ll R$ we do not need to worry about whether the squares touching $0$ are indeed included in $S$. We further simplify the problem by noticing that the *size* of the set of suitable angles $\theta$ for a given centre $x$ only depends on $\rho :=  \Vert x\Vert_2$. So let's fix $0\leq \rho \leq \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}r$. (The upper bound is given by the half diagonal.) To get some visual intuition, take $x = (\rho, 0)$. Let us start in the most "favorable" position, i.e. at $\theta=\pi/4$. The question is by how much we are allowed to skew the square. Note that the point closest to the origin is at distance
$$
d(\theta) = \dfrac{r}{2\cos\theta}.
$$
Hence, we need
$$
\cos\theta \leq \dfrac{r}{2\rho}.
$$
This means that we have the constraint $\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{r}{2\rho}\right)\leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ for $\rho \geq r/2$ and bo constraint for $\rho < r/2$. This means that
$$
m(A) = \dfrac{\pi^2r^2}{8} - 2\pi\int_{r/2}^{\sqrt{2}r/2} \rho \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{r}{2\rho}\right)\mathrm{d}\rho = \dfrac{\pi^2r^2}{8} - \dfrac{\pi(\pi - 2)r^2}{8}.
$$

If I have not made any mistake in any of those integrals, we should get the probability
$$
\dfrac{m(\Omega)}{m(A)} = \text{something very ugly}.
$$

Edit: The following comments try to give a bit more intuitive insight into the notation.

First, note that the uniform distribution on a interval means that the probability of the event is the "length" or "size" of the event, divided by the total length of the interval. The same is going on here: Once we have understood that we want to take $(x,\theta)$ uniformly in $\Omega$, the probability of an event $A$ is the "volume" (because we operate in 3 dimensions now) of $A$, divided by the volume of $\Omega$.

Now, to obtain the volume of a set, we usually integrate, especially if the bodies are complex as in this case. But in the end, it is only "measuring the volume". The $m$ I use is just "the volume of". This "usual" volume is called *Lebsegue measure*, because there other ways to make sense of the word "volume", but in this case this doesn't matter.

I don't think that there is a straightforward way to obtain the explicit expression of the result without using integrals, i.e. by simply using geometric surface/volume formula, but you can always try!

For the other notation: $\Vert (x,y)\Vert_2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is the usual Euclidean distance, $\Vert (x,y)\Vert_\infty = \max\{\vert x\vert, \vert y\vert\}$ is the so-called infinity norm. (There are $\Vert\cdot\Vert_p$-norms for any $p\geq 1$.) When I write $r\ll R$, I mean that $r$ is a lot smaller than $R$. Here, we need this assumption when figuring out how we may describe $A$.

Also, I mainly used WolframAlpha for those horrendous integrals.

Edit 2: There is a lot easier way to calculate $m(A)$. Indeed, mjw (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3966261) correctly points out that, for any given angle $\theta$, the centre must be in a square of side length $r$. That means that
$$
m(A) = \dfrac{\pi}{4}r^2.
$$
I corrected the above mistake.

Comment: You appear to have interpreted the problem as intended (i.e., smaller placed without preference--every instance of a location*angle place within the 'probability space' has equal possibility of existing somewhere within the larger square).  Some of your terminology is beyond my present level of understanding/knowledge. Using 45deg as basis makes sense, and the general flow seems logical, but i don't  know what m(Omega) or m(A) means. "measure"? Also, subscript outside double bar. Does 'p' refer to perimiter? 'd' to deriv.? Feel free to change the tags or tell me what to change them to as well.

Comment: @math  Oh sorry, I wrote in a measure-theoretic way. If you tell me what you are at, I'll rewrite my answer!

Comment: You don't have to totally rewrite it if it's correct, but if you wouldn't mind maybe adding a few explanatory steps or alternative approaches/sub-approaches that can work, that would be superb. Any "theory" appropriately applied is sound, and this isn't the simplest problem.

Comment: @math have you done continuous probabilities already?

Comment: Z-scores and the like of normal curves. Nothing with integrals to find an exact area of messier ranges nor of exact calculations on distributions other than uniform constant or "normal" Gaussian curves.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations addended! It makes more sense to me now. (Some integration then cannot be expressed 'explicitly'? Be this true for negative-degree integrals too ie derivatives?)

Comment: As you see, the integrals can all be solved. But I am not sure whether there is an easy way to calculate the volume without the powerful tool of integrals and antiderivatives. (I admit that I was surprised that there are closed forms for all those integrals, but then again, I do not often calculate integrals explicitly!) I do not exactly understand your last question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117836/discussion-between-mushu-nrek-and-math).

Answer (score 1):

Just to solve the simpler problem to get an approximate answer to check another "exact" answer.  I don't think rotating the square will give an answer too far off ...

Suppose the larger square is $\sqrt{10}$ by $\sqrt{10}$ inches, and the smaller square is $1$ square inch.  Then the center of the smaller square will be uniform within a square with side of length $\sqrt{10}-1$.

The center of the smaller square then needs to be within a square of one square inch near the center square.  Thus

$$P = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{10}-1)^2}= \frac{1}{11-2\sqrt{10}} \approx 0.214.$$

Comment: Would that be a lower bound estimate of the full calculation??

Comment: If indeed it is not far off, which seems reasonable, that would mean that I did some mistake in the integrals, because the other is around 0.1, sad story... I admit that I am not motivated enough to go through them again...

Comment: I think this is a lower bound.  If we choose the angle of rotation first among allowable angles, the area defining the permitted center of the smaller square (which equals the denominator) will shrink, but the numerator will remain constant.

Comment: Hmmmmm.  Looks like $\frac{1}{(\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2})^2}\approx 0.327$ is an upper bound!  so perhaps $0.1$?

Comment: Remember, the side of the larger square is $\sqrt{10}\approx 3.16228$, so rotating could have an effect (contrary to my first impression).

Comment: Now that I corrected one mistake (thanks again!), the result gets worse (around 2.8). This still is in your bound, but your lower bound should be a good approximation.

Comment: Don't give up!${}{}{}$

Comment: Ok I found a mistake: $(\sqrt(10) - 1)^2 = 11 - 2\sqrt(10)$. Then your calculation gives approximately 0.2 which seems closer to $3.1$ and my result!

Comment: Thank you for catching that!