# consolidate codependent continuous probability distributions into one multivariable distribution: how?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Sorry if this has been answered satisfactorily elsewhere; if it has and eluded me, post the link and I shall close this.

This post is motivated by a couple of questions that I’ve asked recently (at [inscribed vs. circumscribed randomly generated similar triangles: which one has more ‘excess’ area on average? by how much](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3966498/867884) = triangles,circles ; and [A square appears randomly within a square of ten time its area. What is probability that the smaller square contains the larger square's center?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3965426/867884) = squares), both which hinge on assigning some sort of probability distribution to two or more interrelated factors. Some of the commenters called an impasse at deciding which type of distribution to use, although in those two geometric cases I believe that a uniform (instead of a gaussian, poisson, chi-square, or other) matches its problem statement. In any case, I don’t know how to combine the two or more distributions into single cohesive one without prioritizing preference to one or another caused by order of calculation.

**What are the appropriate or applicable methods for combining continuous probabilities defined by known relationships with eachother and finite boundaries, in a non-ordered manner, into a single multi-variable probability distribution?**